# Typescript error when typing onChange event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I declared my `state` like below

```
const [updatedStep, updateStepObj] = useState(
    panel === 'add'
        ? new Step()
        : {
                ...selectedStep
          }
);
```

and I have elements like

```
        <TextField
            label="Title"
            value={updatedStep.title}
            onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                updateStepObj({ ...updatedStep, title: e.currentTarget.value })
            }
        />
```

I am getting `Typescript` error for `onChange` event. How can I get rid of `error`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the same type of data for the onChange method as that TextField is declared, so it would be like this:

```
<TextField
   label="Title"
   value={updatedStep.title}
   onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, newValue?: string) =>
       updateStepObj({ ...updatedStep, title: e.currentTarget.value })
   }
/>
```

***Note: to forget about this mess, the best thing to do before adding your method to the event is to hover over it with the mouse and it will tell you the tipado. Then you write the same and perform the action you want.***

Anyway if you want something more exact I add a demo in CodeSandbox and I'll take a look :)